# How can i change the color of a primefaces layout unit?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
            <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="100" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true" style="background-color: red !important;" >
                Header
            </p:layoutUnit>
```

So after trying this only the border of the layout unit becomes colored. I need the entire unit to be colored.

Comment: Tried using css?

Comment: Yes i have , and nothing. I still get only the border to be colored.

Comment: CSS has many more options... External stylesheet, embedded stylesheet, css selectors and more... If this is what you tried, please take a moment to learn some more of css and also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles?rq=1 (it 'effectively' is a duplicate of your question) And keep in mind that css works on client-side html, not server side xhtml